# Cycles baking image sampling

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Does anyone have an idea how to improve quality of this Cycles bake? Using image as source for material color, amount of samples has no effect on how accurately this image is reproduced on baked image, samples only make the lighting more smooth.

[image: baked image has artifacts from bad sampling using image texture]

100 samples produce same quality image sampling as 1 sample. Also I've tried different image interpolation in the node, gaussian filter width, branched path tracing... nothing seems to work.

With procedural pattern the results are similar:
[image: also with procedural texture]

Internal renderer seems to do the job perfectly:
[image: neatly sampled squares]

Comment: Hmmm... What are you referring to as sample, the type of samples one refers to in image editors (like photoshop) or the kind the Blender samples setting refers to (path tracing samples). I am a little confused with what the problem is, and what the desired result is.  Sharing the blend file could help. Perhaps check the size of the image you are baking to, and your UV unwrap. How did you have the texture in BI, as the two engines use different material setups? Did you simply recreate the material for BI? Perhaps there was a mistake recreating, as some options react differently in cycles?

Comment: When you click new image before baking, up the x and y pixel amounts. The more pixels the higher quality the bake.

Comment: I'm refering to how original image is being read. Yes I created material for internal renderer separately. I am very familiar with internal and cycles. But still I'm interested if anyone manages to make a node or render setup on cycles that downscales input texture image properly as internal renderer does.

Inceasing the image size of course increases bake quality but my issue is that for each bake texture pixel the diffuse color is only sampled once or all samples are identical. 

I don't want to bake 16k maps on cycles to get smooth 4k results.